# Modifying a subset of rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have a pandas DataFrame with two columns, A and B. I'd like to modify this DataFrame (or create a copy) so that B is always NaN whenever A is 0. How would I achieve that?

I tried the following

```
df['A'==0]['B'] = np.nan
```

and

```
df['A'==0]['B'].values.fill(np.nan)
```

without success.

Comment: If you are looking for a very fast solution use NumPy's `where` as seen in [this solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307099/modifying-a-subset-of-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe/47086085)

Answer (score 323, accepted):

Use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for label based indexing:

```
df.loc[df.A==0, 'B'] = np.nan
```

The `df.A==0` expression creates a boolean series that indexes the rows, `'B'` selects the column. You can also use this to transform a subset of a column, e.g.:

```
df.loc[df.A==0, 'B'] = df.loc[df.A==0, 'B'] / 2
```

I don't know enough about pandas internals to know exactly why that works, but the basic issue is that sometimes indexing into a DataFrame returns a copy of the result, and sometimes it returns a view on the original object. According to documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#advanced-indexing-with-labels), this behavior depends on the underlying numpy behavior. I've found that accessing everything in one operation (rather than [one][two]) is more likely to work for setting.

Comment: The second part of this is a nice answer to a question that wasn't even asked ;-)  I am wondering if this is still the canonical pandas answer, in particular b/c it's an 
obvious DRY violation, though I assume it is in fact necessary to violate DRY given the constraints of pandas internals?  (I may post exactly this sort of question, in more detail, but wanted to see if you had a quick answer before I did so)

Comment: How to subset a Dataframe that doesn’t have column names , how to subset df just by index ? df.loc[df[0]==0] doesn’t work ... What’s the alternative ? Thank You

Comment: just one hint, if you want to assign another DF e.g. df.loc[df.A==0, df2] be aware that if df2 is continously indexed from 0 to end, it will do a indexwise assignment. So if the filtered **df** has index [1, 4, 5] and **df2** has [1, 2, 3]  just the index 1 will be assigned. This can be prevented by using a unindexed structure on the right hand side, e.g. df.loc[df.A==0, np.array(df2)], then it will be assigned pairwise. This is also the case for pandas .mask() and .where() functions!

Answer (score 111):

[Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-advanced) is from pandas docs on advanced indexing:

The section will explain exactly what you need! Turns out `df.loc` (as .ix has been deprecated -- as many have pointed out below) can be used for cool slicing/dicing of a dataframe. And. It can also be used to set things.

```
df.loc[selection criteria, columns I want] = value
```

So Bren's answer is saying 'find me all the places where `df.A == 0`, select column `B` and set it to `np.nan`'

Comment: Yeah, somehow `loc[selection criteria, columns I want]` perfectly sticks to your mind...

Answer (score 33):

Starting from pandas 0.20 [ix is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated). The right way is to use [df.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

here is a working example

```
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,1,0], "B":[2,0,5]}, columns=list('AB'))
>>> df.loc[df.A == 0, 'B'] = np.nan
>>> df
   A   B
0  0 NaN
1  1   0
2  0 NaN
>>>
```

---

### Explanation:

As explained in the doc [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing), `.loc` *is primarily label based, but may also be used with a boolean array*.

So, what we are doing above is applying `df.loc[row_index, column_index]` by:

- Exploiting the fact that `loc` can take a boolean array as a mask that tells pandas which subset of rows we want to change in `row_index`
- Exploiting the fact `loc` is also label based to select the column using the label `'B'` in the `column_index`

We can use logical, condition or  any operation that returns a series of booleans to construct the array of booleans.  In the above example, we want any `rows` that contain a `0`, for that we can use `df.A == 0`, as you can see in the example below, this returns a series of booleans.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,1,0], "B":[2,0,5]}, columns=list('AB'))
>>> df 
   A  B
0  0  2
1  1  0
2  0  5
>>> df.A == 0 
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
>>>
```

Then, we use the above array of booleans to select and modify the necessary rows:

```
>>> df.loc[df.A == 0, 'B'] = np.nan
>>> df
   A   B
0  0 NaN
1  1   0
2  0 NaN
```

For more information check the advanced indexing documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-advanced).

Answer (score 19):

For a massive speed increase, use NumPy's where function.

#### Setup

Create a two-column DataFrame with 100,000 rows with some zeros.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3, (100000,2)), columns=list('ab'))
```

#### Fast solution with `numpy.where`

```
df['b'] = np.where(df.a.values == 0, np.nan, df.b.values)
```

#### Timings

```
%timeit df['b'] = np.where(df.a.values == 0, np.nan, df.b.values)
685 µs ± 6.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.loc[df['a'] == 0, 'b'] = np.nan
3.11 ms ± 17.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Numpy's `where` is about 4x faster

Comment: I was curious about this so I tested it myself and difference was even greater using other parameters. Numpy was almost 10 times faster at replacing 0s with an integer instead of np.nan. I wonder what takes the extra time.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `.values` in `np.where(df.a.values == 0, np.nan, df.b.values)`? Looks like `np.where(df.a == 0, np.nan, df.b)` also works?

Answer (score 6):

To replace multiples columns convert to numpy array using `.values`:

```
df.loc[df.A==0, ['B', 'C']] = df.loc[df.A==0, ['B', 'C']].values / 2
```

Answer (score 4):

To modify a DataFrame in Pandas, you can use "syntactic sugar" operators like `+=`, `*=`, `/=` etc. So instead of:

```
df.loc[df.A == 0, 'B'] = df.loc[df.A == 0, 'B'] / 2
```

You can write:

```
df.loc[df.A == 0, 'B'] /= 2
```

To replace values with `NaN` you can use Pandas methods [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) or [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html). For example:

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [0, 0, 4]})

   A  B
0  1  0
1  2  0
2  3  4

df['A'].mask(df['B'] == 0, inplace=True) # other=np.nan by default
# df['A'].where(df['B'] != 0, inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
     A  B
0  NaN  0
1  NaN  0
2  3.0  4
```

Answer (score 2):

**Alternatives:**

*no 1 looks best to me, but oddly I can't find the supporting documentation for it*

1. Filter column as series (note: filter comes after column being written to, not before)

*dataframe.column[filter condition]=values to change to*

```
df.B[df.A==0] = np.nan
```

2. [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

*dataframe.loc[filter condition, column to change]=values to change to*

```
df.loc[df.A == 0, 'B'] = np.nan
```

3. [numpy where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

*dataframe.column=np.where(filter condition, values if true, values if false)*

```
import numpy as np
df.B = np.where(df.A== 0, np.nan, df.B)
```

4. [apply lambda](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

*dataframe.column=df.apply(lambda row: value if condition true else value if false, use rows not columns)*

```
df.B = df.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x['A']==0 else x['B'],axis=1)
```

5. [zip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) and list syntax

*dataframe.column=[valuse if condition is true else value if false for elements a,b in list from zip function of columns a and b]*

```
df.B = [np.nan if a==0 else b for a,b in zip(df.A,df.B)]
```