# Python- How to select rows from a multiIndexed data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I currently have a data frame in which each row is indexed by a physical 3d coordinate. Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
            ind pos
x   y   z       
1.0 8.0 2.0 0   (52.3311, 240.997, 70.7449)
        2.0 1   (54.8969, 241.985, 72.116)
        2.0 2   (51.9996, 240.91, 73.2884)
        2.0 3   (51.765, 240.269, 71.5289)
        2.0 4   (53.5773, 243.276, 69.569)
        2.0 5   (53.1426, 240.779, 71.912)
```

I want to select all the entries where any of the coordinates (x,y,z) are equal to some value. What is the most efficient way to do this? I have quite a large datset (~ 3 million entries) and I want to select all the rows in which any of x, y, or z are equal to a value 33.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selecting from multi-index pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835077/selecting-from-multi-index-pandas)

Comment: what do you mean ' I want to select all the rows in which and of x, y, or z' are equal to a value 33?

Comment: Only know one way - [query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method). Interested to see a comparative analysis of efficiencies of alternatives though.

Comment: query() did exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
df[1.0,8.0,2.0]
```

Also `xs` help you manage multiindex:

```
df.xs(('1.0', '8.0', '2.0'))
```

PS: Quotes are in case your indexes are strings and not floats

Comment: The thing is, I don't know how to use xs to select slices where any of the values could be what I want.  For example, say I make this key value 20. I don't know how to use xs to select rows in which x is 20, or y is 20, or z is 20, or x and y are 20, or y and z are 20, etc. Additionally, x,y,z can take on a wide range of values so I am not able to just search using df[x, y, z] sadly.

Comment: Then your question is not conveying the problem your trying to solve. asking the right question will give you half of the solution. I'm finding hard to follow what you are trying to do. But there are many people smarter than me, they should come to your rescue anytime now