# How to Select Specific Columns in Pandas DataFrame Using Multiple Boolean Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find a very good, comprehensive answer to the above question.

Let's take the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df['Category'] = pd.Series(['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat1', 'Cat2'])
df:
            A         B         C         D Category
  0  0.057456  0.462712 -1.245539  0.095947     Cat1
  1  0.741688  0.353600  1.130754 -1.692440     Cat2
  2  0.638623 -0.109566  0.118509 -0.692661     Cat1
  3 -0.905806  0.284818 -0.094696 -1.325617     Cat2
```

I understand the basic nomenclature of using `df.A` or `df['A']` to select column `A`, and `df[['A', 'B']]` to select both columns `A` and `B`.

And if I want to pass in boolean conditions I can do things like `df[df.A > 0]` to return rows where `df.A` is greater than 0.  And I can include multiple conditions like `df[(df.A > 0) & (df.Category == 'Cat1')]` to include multiple conditions.

One thing I am not seeing though, is how I could select a subset of the dataframe columns with the same two boolean conditions used above.

Two approaches I have tried without success:

```
df['B'].where(df.A > 0)
```

This returns all of the rows in the index, whereas I'd only like the ones that return `True` for said condition.

I've also tried using `query` without success because it can't be used on a Series.

So `df['A'].query(some condition)` returns an error message.

Ideally the solution I'm looking for has the following conditions:

1. Can be used both on single columns or multiple columns.  Ie, you can choose both `df['A']` and `df['B']` with it.
2. Can use multiple boolean conditions if you want to, not just one.
3. Only returns the rows that evaluate to `True` for the condition, not all the rows.
4. Ideally is syntactically simple, but if that's not possible then so be it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for `.loc`

```
df.loc[df.A>0,'B']
0    0.462712
1    0.353600
2   -0.109566
Name: B, dtype: float64
df.loc[(df.A>0)&(df.B<0),['B','C']]
          B         C
2 -0.109566  0.118509
```

Comment: You are too fast! And congratulations for 100K!

Answer (score 2):

You are proceeding correctly with your `df['B'].where(df.A > 0)` condition. However, just append few more function after it to achieve only `True` results.

An example with multiple (can pass single too) condition:

```
df[['B','C']].where((df.A > 1) & (df.D>0)).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a variation of [@W-B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53953061/1534017) using `query`:

```
df.query('A > 0 and B < 0').loc[:, ['B', 'C']]
```

or

```
df.query('A > 0 and B < 0')[['B', 'C']]
```

will also print

```
          B         C
2 -0.109566  0.118509
```

Comment: @Datanovice: What do you mean by "only work on the index"? I looked at the four requirements listed in the question, and think that `query` addresses all of them. It also [works fine on different index levels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49045951/1534017).

Comment: Apologies, I should have consulted the docs first. I was thinking of the.   .filter function. Thanks for teaching me something new.

Comment: @Datanovice: No worries :)