# Pandas option to keep levels after xs operation

Tags: pandas

Is there a way to perform a cross-section on a hierarchical dataframe that returns the dataframe without the searched levels being dropped?

That is, if you have a dataframe with index.names = ['month','year'] and perform the following command

```
newdf = df.xs(('January'),level=('month'))
```

such that the new dataframe retains the month index?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update a subset of a MultiIndexed pandas DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552997/how-to-update-a-subset-of-a-multiindexed-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that drop_level kwarg has been added to version 0.13 for this exact purpose.