# pandas DataFrame set non-contiguous sections

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like below and would like for B to be 1 for n rows *after* the 1 in column A (where below n = 2)

```
index  A   B
0      0   0
1      1   0
2      0   1
3      0   1
4      1   0
5      0   1
6      0   1
7      0   0
8      1   0
9      0   1
```

I think I can do it using .ix similar to this example but not sure how. I'd like to do it in a single in pandas-style selection command if possible. (Ideally not using rolling_apply.)
[Modifying a subset of rows in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307099/modifying-a-subset-of-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

EDIT: the application is that the 1 in column A is "ignored" if it falls within n rows of the previous 1. As per the comments, for n = 2 then, and these example:

A = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], B should be = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
A = [1, 1, 0, 0], B should be [0, 1, 1, 0]

Comment: What if you have `1, 0, 1, 0, 1` or `1, 1, 0, 0` in column `A`, how do you want B to be?

Comment: Good question: ideally if it was [1, 0, 1, 0, 1] and n=2, then B would be [0, 1, 1, 0, 0] (i.e. the first 1 in column A needs to propagate its 2 more 1's but then the 1 in column A index=2, is "knocked out" b/c there is a one already in column B for that index)

Comment: For your second example A = [1,1,0,0], I would ideally like B to be = [0, 1, 1, 0] if n = 2