# Randomly assign values to subset of rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python 2.7.11 with Anaconda.

I understand how to set the value of a subset of rows of a `Pandas` `DataFrame` like [Modifying a subset of rows in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307099/modifying-a-subset-of-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe), but I need to randomly set these values.

Say I have the dataframe `df` below. How can I randomly set the values of `group == 2` so they are not all equal to 1.0?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,2,2,2], columns = ['group'])
df['value'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['group'] == 2, 'value'] = np.random.randint(0,5)

print df
   group  value
0      1    NaN
1      1    NaN
2      1    NaN
3      2    1.0
4      2    1.0
5      2    1.0
```

`df` should look something like the below:

```
print df
   group  value
0      1    NaN
1      1    NaN
2      1    NaN
3      2    1.0
4      2    4.0
5      2    2.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must determine the size of group 2

```
g2 = df['group'] == 2
df.loc[g2, 'value'] = np.random.randint(5, size=g2.sum())
print(df)

   group  value
0      1    NaN
1      1    NaN
2      1    NaN
3      2    3.0
4      2    4.0
5      2    2.0
```