# substraction of series to databases

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, spectrum

I try to correct some glitches in my spectra and I got stuck on the last part, the implementation... FML
I have cleaend and prepared the file.

Between the times 70 and 75 lies a glitch in the detector which we need to correct.
We identified and obtained the difference **now** we need to add this difference to each of the 1024 rows up to 70 and leave the 75 and further without any change.
Adding the corrected and non-corrected values.

I have really tryied several ways and I cannot seem to obtain result, I am unsure on how to approach this correctly or if I need to define the indexes clearer.

```
spec= raw_spec_raw  # 1024 x 199 csv wavelength/time
pre_glitch = spec['70.197969989']
post_glitch = spec['75.281351195']
diff = post_glitch - pre_glitch   # series with 1024 elements
corr=[]
```

Any help would be appreciated, at least a hint. I have seen so many complex examples or other which are crazy over-simplified and do no teach anything.

Thank you and have a good day.
[This a graphical description of how simple it is, :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fke40.jpg)

Comment: Is `diff` a single value? You should always include a minimal example of your data. Please read [mre]. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Related: [Modifying a subset of rows in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307099/modifying-a-subset-of-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe). Applies to columns also - `df.loc[:,column_slice] = df.loc[:,column_slice] +1` where `column_slice` might be `'75.281351195':`.

Comment: [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data)