# Converting strings into np.nan

Tags: pandas

`energy[energy["Energy Supply"] == "..."]["Energy Supply"] = np.nan`

So I've tried converting strings in the column called "Energy Supply" into np.nan but nothing happens when I run this code

I've wrongfully typed

`energy[energy["Energy Supply"] == "..."] = np.nan`

And it has successfuly turned the whole DF where this "..."  string is present into np.nan but when I tried the same with only "Energy Supply" column nothing happened

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, this is 6yo, but perhaps still relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307099/modifying-a-subset-of-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: By running `energy[energy["Energy Supply"] == "..."]["Energy Supply"] = np.nan` you create a new Series, which you modify and discard immediately. Use `energy.loc[energy["Energy Supply"] == "...", "Energy Supply"] = np.nan`

Comment: Alternatively: `energy["Energy Supply"] = energy["Energy Supply"].replace('...', np.nan)`